# Default display switches from external monitor to notebook's monitor after login

Tags: external-display, amd-radeon, ubuntu-11.04

I'm using ThinkPad x120e with Ubuntu 11.04. I updated the graphics driver using "Additional Drivers" program (AMD Radeon™ HD 6300M Series Graphics.) When I work at home, I want to use my external monitor. So, I changed some settings using ATI Catalyst Control Center, disabled notebook's display, set external monitor as default and restarted.

Now, login screen is only shown in external monitor just like I wanted, however when I log in to my account the display switches from external monitor to notebook's monitor, and external monitor is disabled. When I go back to login screen, display switches again. I want to use external monitor only as long as it is connected to the computer. Any ideas how I can do that, and why the computer is behaving like that?

Comment: Can you use the "monitors" application in Ubuntu to configure your display? I have an X120E also running 11.04, heh, cool. Though I've avoided switching back and forth monitors like that on Linux, just seems like it'd be a source of misery. But I believe there's been a lot of work in the last few years, I think xrandr was created to really aid with this sort of thing...

Comment: Yes, I can see monitors application, but it doesn't give me any options I can use. That's why I'm using Ati Catalyst.

Comment: I see. I suggest you then try removing the Catalyst driver, completely.. Then try running on the open source ATI driver ("radeon"). You *may* be able to use that driver for this. Though I wouldn't be especially optimistic. There are ways of doing this somewhat decently if you can stand to restart your X session every time you want to switch display configurations.